# How to deal with errors in function nesting and calling functions within other functions

Tags: c#, asp.net

Scenario:
I have to check for user input (a string) that shouldn't contain `<.%?/` symbols and if it does I remove them. I have 20 different places where I've to check it, actually, 20 different pages with each 20 different controls.

So I wrote a function like the following shortened example:

```
public string MyFunction (string userinput)
{
    return userinput.replace("<"," ");
}
```

Now if I want to call this function from within another function and there's an error in this function's `try catch` block I want it to write an error to a `Label` on the main page, without interrupting the second function.
Also i am thinking of implementing conditional statement function calls too.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you are getting at?

Comment: is it poseble that to stop a function call that was call by some function to stop the caller function and terminate the call in it self when a certain condition occurs

Comment: Note: your code is illegal and does nothing. But I think your question is about catching errors, not about how to make a replacement function work, correct?

Comment: What language do you use, C#, VB, Ruby something else?

Comment: your code example above looks like javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually it's best to let the calling function catch your error and to act upon it. Something like this (assuming C#, but your question wasn't clear about that and didn't have a working example):

```
try {
    string resplacedString = yourReplaceFunction(userInput);
} catch (MyException e) {
    Label1.Text = "An error occurred." + e.Description;
}
```

Comment: thanks dude ... just what i was thinking ...